# how to pass an array with different sizes to my c++ function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, input

I'm not sure if this is possible but i'm open to ideas.

I have a c++ function. It does some calculation to arrays that are being defined by users as inputs and will generate two output values. Let's call it "myfunction" and it looks something like this:

> void myfunction(double array1[18],double array[9],double array [2],double *output1, double *output2)

I want to make this function more generic so that it is able to take in arrays of different size. Meaning, I want users of this function to be able to define array inputs of other size.

For example,

> void myfunction(double array1[81],double array[27],double array [3],double *output1, double *output2)

Mathematically, "myfunction" is able to calculate accurate outputs despite the array size. I don't want to make a duplicate of "myfunction" because there are a total of 5 different sets of array size that the user can define as inputs.

Any ideas? thank you in advance

Comment: Have a look at `std::vector` and `std::array`

Comment: `void myfunction(double array1[18],double array[9],double array [2],double *output1, double *output2)` -- The first three arguments are **not** arrays.  That declaration is exactly the same as this one: `void myfunction(double *array1, double *array, double *array, double *output1, double *output2);`.  The array that is passed decays to a pointer -- all size information in this form of declaration is lost.

Comment: Adding to @KhouriGiordano, accepting `std::vector` by reference (or `const` reference when you don't intend to modify it) will have roughly the same performance, and allow you to inspect the `.size()` of each input to determine what you need to loop over.

Comment: Plan A: user `std::vector`.  Plan B (if you must use 1-dimensional arrays): simply don't declare a size: `void myfunction(double *array1,double *array2,double *array3,double *output1, double *output2)`

Comment: Are the array sizes known at compile time? And how are the output lengths calculated?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either pass a `std::vector` or use a `template`:

```
template <std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2, std::size_t N3> // and so on...
void work_with_arrays(double (&arr1)[N1], double (&arr2)[N2], double (&arr3)[N3]){
    std::cout << "First arr of a size: " << N1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "Second arr of a size: " << N2 << "\n";
    std::cout << "Third arr of a size: " << N3 << "\n";
};

int main() {
    double something[32];
    double fewer[13];
    double maybe_byte[8];

    work_with_arrays(something, fewer, maybe_byte);
}
```

The code outputs:

```
First arr of a size: 32
Second arr of a size: 13
Third arr of a size: 8
```

---

**Explanation:**

One should know that the argument of type `T[]` (`T` being any type) *decays* to `T*`. If we're dealing with a pointer to an array, we have no information about its length, which is quite unfortunate, given the fact that lengths of fixed-length arrays are known at compile time and could be visible everywhere we work with them.

One should also know that a *function template* is **not** a function. It is a template used to create functions. For every different set of `N#` used in the example above, there will be a function generated for our use.

**What is the workaround to the decaying problem?**

Instead of passing a raw `T[]`, we should pass a *reference* to `T[]`. That way the type does not decay and the size of the array will be known.

**Syntax?**

One could notice that `T (&name)[some_size]` looks at least bizarre. The parentheses are required, since plain `T &name[size]` would be interpreted as `T& name[size]`, which is an *array of references*, not a *reference to an array*.

**Conclusion:**

Being able to detect the size of a passed-as-argument array, we don't want to limit ourselves with one or two cases - we want to *cover them all*, so we use a `template` to generate functions with `N#` of needed value.

Comment: It is good to add the details, like what is "double (&arr1)[N1]" and how it work to get easily understand the "New Contributor"

Comment: @Swapnil I edited my answer by adding explanations to selected issues

Answer (score 3):

You can have your function take in a `vector` which is a "dynamically resizable array". You can iterate over it, or get its size as needed. See its [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;  // I'm too lazy to prepend std:: as needed.
void myfunction(const vector<double>& array1, 
                const vector<double>& array2,
                const vector<double>& array3, 
                vector<double>& output1, vector<double>& output2) {

}
```

If that is not possible, then have it take in extra arguments indicating the size of the arrays.

```
void myfunction(double *array1,
                double *array2, 
                double *array3,
                int size1,
                int size2,
                int size3,
                double *output1, 
                double *output2) {

}
```

but this is really ugly. Just go with the first option.

Comment: Not only is the second method "ugly", it is very easy for the client to make a mistake if the size is not correct.  A `vector` knows its size by using the `vector::size()` function, thus never is incorrect.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Agree completely. However, to be realistic, there are some platforms or constrains that sometimes prohibit the use of complex data structures (although vector is not *that* complex) and sometimes dealing with legacy code that cannot be refactored easily so this is a *really desperate* option.

Comment: In those cases, and if C99 is available, it would be better to use a struct with a flexible array member.

Comment: @CinderBiscuits Yes. Forgot about that. In fact, that brings up another option which is template specialize a function that takes in `std::array` as arguments. Essentially @Fureeish answer without raw pointers.